# Convert an hex string into int using c#

Tags: string, integer, hex

I need to convert a string which cointains an hex value into an 8 bit integer.

For example I have a string

test="3A"

I would like to convert into int which means 58.

Is there a particular function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with function ***Convert.ToInt32***

int value=Convert.ToInt32("3A", 16);